# Raspberry Pi Arduino Installer broken

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberrypi

I am tring to use ShorTie8's new arduino ARM installer on my RPI B+ by copying this into my terminal:

> cd
>
> sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
>
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ShorTie8/Arduino_IDE/master/Arduino_IDE_builder.bash
>
> chmod +x Arduino_IDE_builder.bash
>
> sudo ./Arduino_IDE_builder.bash
>
> sudo Arduino/build/linux/work/./arduino
>
> sudo Arduino/build/linux/work/./install.sh
>
> sudo apt-get install -y mercurial subversion build-essential gperf bison ant texinfo zip automake flex libusb-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libtinfo-dev pkg-config libwxbase3.0-dev libtools

But Getting The following Error at sudo ./Arduino_IDE_builder.bash

> - echo -e '\n\nConfiguration values\n\n'
>
> Configuration values
>
> - Stable=1.6.7
> - Update_me=yes
> - Silence_is_Golden=yes
> - echo -e '\n\nSystem check\n\n'
>
> System check
>
> ++ date
>   + start_time='Sat 13 Feb 11:12:37 GMT 2016'
>   ++ pwd
>   + Start_Directory=/home/pi
>   ++ pwd
>   + Working_Directory=/home/pi/Arduino/build
>   + echo -e '\n\nChecking for root .. \n'
>
> Checking for root ..
>
> ++ id -u
>   + '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
>   + echo 'Yuppers .. :)~'
>   Yuppers .. :)~
>   + [[ yes == \y\e\s ]]
>   + echo -e '\n\nChecking to see if I'\''m update\n'
>
> Checking to see if I'm update
>
> - git remote update
>     fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually downloading a file from the github repository, check out the repository properly with `git clone 《repository》`

Comment: It is a bash script. How can I edit it without messing up?

Comment: Pardon? Who said anything about editing anything? Just clone the github repository like you would with any other github repository. Delete your current bash script, you don't want it.